# Number of 1 in binary representation of n

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, generating-functions, digits

Let $1(n)$ be the number of digits $1$ in binary representation of number $n$.

For example, $13=1101_2$ so $1(13)=3\\$

Is there explicit form of $\,\,\sum{1(i)x^i} $?

I checked OEIS and didn't find information about this sequence (1,1,2,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,...)

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000120

Comment: Can you be more explicit how to obtain the sequence?

Comment: Your version is missing $1(4)=1$

Comment: For those looking to actually count binary 1s in computer program code, you may enjoy reading [fast bit-counting routines](http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The generating function you ask about, more typically written as $\sum_{i\ge 0} s_2(i) x^i$, can be expressed as 
$$\frac{1}{1-x} \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{x^{2^m}}{1+x^{2^m}}$$ 
The number of 1's in the binary expansion is just the sums of digits; there also exists a generalization for sums of digits function in other bases. For details, references and further information, see for example  ["Generating Functions for the Digital Sum and Other Digit Counting Sequences"](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL12/Ruskey2/ruskey14.pdf) by Adams-Watters and Ruskey (Journal of Integer Sequences, 2009)

Answer (score 7):

By the way, the reason why the OP did not find the sequence in the OEIS is that he/she wrote down the first few terms incorrectly.  They are 0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3, ..., which is sequence http://oeis.org/A000120 .

Comment: This hsould be a comment